# Can you create a generated ts vector column on a shadow property?

Tags: entity-framework-core, npgsql

I'd like to create a generated tsvector column using npgsql / dotnet on a shadow property.  I do not want to place the tsvector column in the entity class as I'd like to keep the domain entities agnostic of any specific database.

One way that may work is to use a shadow property for the tsvector column.  I am able to create the tsvector column and index, but have not been able to figure out how to create generated column definition.

If the property exists in the domain entity, I can use the following:

```
        builder
            .HasGeneratedTsVectorColumn(
                c => c.SearchVector,
                "english",
                c => new { c.Number, c.Name })
            .HasIndex(p => p.SearchVector)
            .HasMethod("GIN");
```

If the property is not in the domain, but rather a shadow property, I tried something like the foolowing:

```
        builder
            .Property<NpgsqlTsVector>("search_vector");

        builder
            .HasGeneratedTsVectorColumn(
                    c => EF.Property<NpgsqlTsVector>(c, "search_vector"),
                    "english",
                    c => new { c.ClientId, c.Name })
            .HasIndex("search_vector")
            .HasMethod("GIN");
```

Unfortunately, this does not work and, when generating the migrations, issues the following error:

```
 ---> System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
 ---> System.ArgumentException: The expression 'c => Property(c, "search_vector")' is not a valid member access expression. The expression should represent a simple property or field access: 't => t.MyProperty'. (Parameter 'memberAccessExpression')
```

Is it possible to create the definition of the generated column for a shadow property?

Of course, also interested if there are other ways to accomplish this besides using a shadow property.

Thanks for any help,
Eric